# What is meant by "CPU generates logical address space"?

Tags: operating-system

As far as I read from the book(correct me I am wrong) after a compiler puts the compiled code in the storage, the CPU creates logical addresses and those logical addresses are mapped to physical memory through MMU(Memory Management Unit).Also I know that CPU directly cannot access anything other than the physical memory.

Then how does CPU produce logical addresses for the process in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have a bit of confusion about what things do.

The operating system defines the logical address space by setting up page tables that logical pages to physical page frames. The operating system loads hardware registers of the CPU so that it knows about the page tables it has defined.

This use of page tables to define logical address spaces is an integral part of a modern CPU. In some systems, the only use of physical addresses is within page tables.

The compiler generates an object code file that describes the instructions and data used and created.

The linker combines object code into an executable file that defines how the program will be loaded into memory.

The loader reads the instructions in an executable file and sets up the logical addresses space to run the program. The loader calls system routines that set up the page tables the define the logical addresses space.

For example, where the executable has read-only data, the loader will call OS routines to creates read-only pages in the logical address space and map them to the data in the executable file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.
But I was wondering when does loading actually occur.I know when we type in gcc <file name> it creates an object code and links it with libraries but does loading occur now or only after we type in ./a.out.

Comment: The loading occurs only after you run the program.

Comment: I (probably) read the same book and got confused at the same point. The answer is satisfying to me. And one note; loading might happen in a lazy or eager fashion.